# Preventing double form submission not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to disable button after submiting to prevent from double submission. I added `onsubmit="add_orders.disabled = true; return true;"` to form tag but after submitting the form, the button is disabled, website is reloading but nothing changed (form is not submitting). My code:

```
<form method="post" action="add.php" onsubmit="add_orders.disabled = true; return true;">
                          <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                </div>
                                <p class="card-text">
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" name="orders_query" placeholder="Wklej treść zapytania SQL z zamówienia..." required></textarea>
                                </p>
                              </div>
                              <div class="card-footer">
                                <button  type="submit" type="button" class="btn btn-raised btn-secondary" name="add_orders">Dodaj zamówienie</button>
                              </div>
                            </div>
        </form>
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['add_orders'])) {
    $tresc = $_POST['orders_query'];

    if (empty($tresc)) { array_push($errors, "Query cannot be empty!"); }
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        if (mysqli_multi_query($con, $tresc)) {
            $_SESSION['success'] = "Added!";
        } else {
            echo "Error!" . mysqli_error($conn);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is this HTML code part of `add.php`?

Comment: `button  type="submit" type="button"` isn't valid

Comment: Yes, at the top of add.php there is an include with php file with directives for submitting this form, so thats the reason why action="add.php"

Comment: See my update. You cannot disable a button if you test for it on the server

Comment: The dupe is jQuery but the reasoning is the same. Either do NOT actually disable the submit if you are testing it OR use a hidden field you can set when you click the submit button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have two types on a button

You are using the button name to test if the form is submitted in the PHP, so you need the button to NOT be disabled. Change the event in css instead

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("orderForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // remove when tested
    document.querySelector("[name=add_orders]").classList.add("stopClick")
  })
})
```

```css
.stopClick {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" id="orderForm" action="add.php">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="modal-header">
    </div>
    <p class="card-text">
      <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" name="orders_query" placeholder="Wklej treść zapytania SQL z zamówienia..." required></textarea>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-raised btn-secondary" name="add_orders">Dodaj zamówienie</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Previous answer before OP showed the PHP**

If you just want to disable you can do this

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  document.getElementById("orderForm").addEventListener("submit",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // remove when tested
    document.querySelector("[name=add_orders]").disabled=true;
  })
})
```

```html
<form method="post" id="orderForm" action="add.php" >
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="modal-header">
    </div>
    <p class="card-text">
      <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" name="orders_query" placeholder="Wklej treść zapytania SQL z zamówienia..." required></textarea>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-raised btn-secondary" name="add_orders">Dodaj zamówienie</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Result is the same - button is disableing, website is refreshing, but no result (PHP not processing?)

Comment: See my update...

Comment: I added PHP at the top :) Disabling will not working if I use it on the server?

Comment: No. The button is not sent with the request if it is disabled

Comment: Thank you :) pointer-events: none; solved my problem :)